# Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Tags: php, mysql

I have a custom php page in my wordpress site. On this page I am registering new users. In the backend I am calling a function that is inserting the collected data into a MySql DB.
Every time I submit data in the form I am getting a 'Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.' error.
The weirdest part is that the exact same code is working on another site (non wordpress) that I have made.

Here's the code extract

```
if (isset($_POST['register_form'])) {
register();
}

function register(){
    //echo '<script>alert("Welcome to Geeks for Geeks")</script>';
    // call these variables with the global keyword to make them available in function
    global $db, $errors, $username, $email;

    // receive all input values from the form. Call the e() function
    // defined below to escape form values
    $username    =  $_POST['element_1'];
    $email       =  $_POST['element_6'];
    $password_1  =  $_POST['element_2'];
    $password_2  =  $_POST['element_3'];

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);

        $query = "INSERT INTO 6vr_users (user_login, user_email, user_pass)  VALUES('".$username."', '".$email."', '".$password."')";
            if(mysqli_query($db, $query)){
                echo "Records inserted successfully.";
                             } 
            else {
                                echo "ERROR: Could not execute query: $query. " . mysqli_error($db);
                }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's just what the error says and you're issuing an implicit or explicit commit in a trigger, have you checked that? (Side note: you seem to have a textbook SQL injection vulnerability, and using plain MD5 hashes to store passwords is not very different from storing them in clear.)

Comment: Do you have any triggers registered on `6vr_users` table?

Comment: Thanks a lot u-nik, I did not realize that I had a trigger! It's working fine now.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I will use mysqli_stmt_bind_param to insert values. As far as MD5 is concerned, is there a better way to store the password?

Comment: The [builtin password functions](https://www.php.net/password).